# Why does a specific Worksheet need be activated to run macro correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

In posing this question I have made certain that all `cells` and `worksheets` have been appropriately qualified, ruled out speed factors (`DoEvents` etc), debugged line by line (runs successfully in debug mode) and tried activating `ws1` whilst no other workbooks remain open. No errors generated.

The only circumstance whereby the code successfully executes in run mode is when `ws1` is viewed at the same time as running. Why?

Code:

```
Sub Q()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Part 1
    
        Dim Str1, _
            Str2, _
            Str3, _
            Str4, _
            Str5, _
            Str6, _
            Str7, _
            Str8, _
            Str9, _
            Str10, _
            Str11, _
            Str12, _
            Str13, _
            Str14, _
            Str15, _
            Str16, _
            Str17 As String, _
            wsf As WorksheetFunction
            
        Dim i, _
            j, _
            k, _
            M, _
            x, _
            lRow1, _
            lRow2, _
            lRow3, _
            lRow4, _
            lRow5, _
            Long1, _
            Long2, _
            Long3, _
            Long4, _
            myDate As Long

            Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
            Str9 = "#QU004"
            myDate = Application.InputBox("Select date in YYYYMMDD format:")
            
            Str1 = "[String]" _
                & myDate
            Str2 = Str1 & ".csv"
            Str3 = "[String]" _
                & Str2
            Str4 = Str1
            
        Dim Year, _
            Month, _
            Day As Integer, _
            Dt As Date
            
            Year = Left(myDate, 4)
            Month = Right(Left(myDate, 6), 2)
            Day = Right(myDate, 2)
            Dt = DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)
            
            Str5 = "[String]" _
                & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Dt), "yyyymmdd")
            Str6 = Str5 & ".xls"
            Str7 = "[String]" _
                & "[String]" _
                & "[String]" _
                & Str6
            Str8 = "[String]" _
                & Right(myDate, 2) _
                & Left(Right(myDate, 4), 2) _
                & Right(Left(myDate, 4), 2)

        Dim wb1, _
            wb2, _
            wb3 As Workbook
            
            Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Str3)
            Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Str7, , , , "[String]")
            wb1.Activate
        
        Dim ws1, _
            ws2, _
            ws3, _
            ws4 As Worksheet
            
            Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("[Name]")
            Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(Str4)
            Set ws3 = wb3.Worksheets(Str8)
            Set ws4 = wb1.Worksheets("[Name]")
        
        Dim rMatch As Variant

        Dim Rng1, _
            Rng2, _
            Rng3, _
            Rng4 As Range
         
            With ws1
                lRow3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                lRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng3 = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lRow3, 23))
                Set Rng4 = .Range(.Cells(3, 28), .Cells(lRow4, 51))
            End With
        
        Dim PTable1, _
            PTable2, _
            PTable3, _
            PTable4 As PivotTable
            
            Set PTable1 = wb1.Worksheets("[Name]").Cells(4, 2).PivotTable
            Set PTable2 = wb1.Worksheets("[Name]").Cells(4, 5).PivotTable
            Set PTable3 = ws4.Cells(4, 17).PivotTable
            Set PTable4 = ws4.Cells(4, 20).PivotTable
        
    ' Part 2
    
        ' Fusion wb
            
            With ws2
            
                lRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow2, 23))
            
                ' Sort
                
                    With ws2.Sort
                        .SortFields.Clear
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SetRange Range("A2:W" & lRow2)
                        .Header = xlNo
                        .Apply
                    End With
    
                    If lRow4 > 2 Then
                        Rng4.Clear
                    End If
                    Rng2.Copy ws1.Cells(3, 28)
                    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
            End With
        
        ' NT wb
        
            With ws3
                
                lRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lRow1, 23))
        
                ' Delete Str9
                
                    For i = lRow1 To 3 Step -1
                        rMatch = Application.Match(Str9, .Cells(i, 9), 0)
                        If Not IsError(rMatch) Then
                            .Rows(i).Delete
                        End If
                    Next i
                    
                ' Sort
                
                    With ws3.Sort
                        .SortFields.Clear
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B" & lRow1), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I3:I" & lRow1), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K3:K" & lRow1), Order:=xlAscending
                        .SetRange Range("A3:W" & lRow1)
                        .Header = xlNo
                        .Apply
                    End With
            
                If lRow3 > 2 Then
                    Rng3.Clear
                End If
                Rng1.Copy ws1.Cells(3, 1)
                wb3.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
            End With
                                    
            ' Part 3
                                                   
                With ws1
                
                    For j = 3 To lRow1 + 3
                    
                        ' NT data reformatting
                            
                            If Not j > 3 Then
                            
                                For M = 3 To lRow1 + 3
                                    
                                    If .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                        .Cells(M, 2) = Left(.Cells(M, 2), 1) _
                                                        & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 15), 1) _
                                                        & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 19), 1)
                                        ElseIf .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                            .Cells(M, 2) = UCase(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 3))
                                    End If
                                    If .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                        .Cells(M, 2) = UCase(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 1) _
                                                            & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 14), 1) _
                                                            & Left(Right(.Cells(M, 2), 9), 1) _
                                                            & Left(Right(.Cells(M, 2), 9), 1) _
                                                            & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 23), 1))
                                        ElseIf .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                            .Cells(M, 2) = Left(.Cells(M, 2), 1) _
                                                            & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 10), 1) _
                                                            & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 20), 1)
                                    End If
                                    If .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                        .Cells(M, 2) = Left(.Cells(M, 2), 1) _
                                                        & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 7), 1) _
                                                        & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 14), 1) _
                                                        & Right(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 23), 1) _
                                                        & Left(Right(.Cells(M, 2), 7), 1)
                                        ElseIf .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                            .Cells(M, 2) = Left(.Cells(M, 2), 3)
                                    End If
                                    If .Cells(M, 2) = "[String]" Then
                                        .Cells(M, 2) = UCase(Left(.Cells(M, 2), 7))
                                    End If
                                    
                                    .Cells(M, 9) = Right(.Cells(M, 9), 6)
                                    If Left(.Cells(M, 9), 1) <> "Q" And .Cells(M, 2) <> "" Then
                                        .Cells(M, 9) = "Q" & .Cells(M, 9)
                                    End If
        
                                Next M
                                
                            End If
                            
                            ' j
                                ' NT
                                    Str10 = .Cells(j, 2)
                                    Str11 = .Cells(j, 9)
                                    Long1 = .Cells(j, 11)
                                ' Fusion
                                    Str12 = .Cells(j, 28)
                                    Str13 = .Cells(j, 29)
                                    Long2 = .Cells(j, 33)
                        
                            ' Part 4
                            
                                ' Matching and alignment
                                                               
                                    If Str12 = "" Or Str10 = "" Then
                                        Do
                                            Exit Do
                                        Loop
                                        ElseIf Str10 <> Str12 Or _
                                        Str11 <> Str13 Or _
                                        Long1 <> Long2 Then
                                            k = j
                                            Do
                                                k = k + 1
                                                If k = lRow1 Then
                                                    x = j
                                                    Do
                                                        x = x + 1
                                                        Str16 = .Cells(x, 28)
                                                        Str17 = .Cells(x, 29)
                                                        Long4 = .Cells(x, 33)
                                                        If Str16 = Str10 And _
                                                            Str17 = Str11 And _
                                                            Long4 = Long1 Then
                                                            .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j + lRow4, 23)).Cut _
                                                                Destination:=.Cells(x, 1)
                                                                Exit Do
                                                        End If
                                                    Loop While x < lRow2
                                                End If
                                                Str14 = .Cells(k, 2)
                                                Str15 = .Cells(k, 9)
                                                Long3 = .Cells(k, 11)
                                                If Str14 = Str12 And _
                                                    Str15 = Str13 And _
                                                    Long3 = Long2 Then
                                                    .Range(.Cells(j, 28), .Cells(j + lRow1, 42)).Cut _
                                                        Destination:=.Cells(k, 28)
                                                        Exit Do
                                                End If
                                            Loop While k < lRow1
                                    End If
                    Next j
                            
                    lRow5 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(3, 24), .Cells(lRow5, 27)).FillDown
                    PTable1.RefreshTable
                    PTable2.RefreshTable
                    PTable3.RefreshTable
                    PTable4.RefreshTable
                    
                    ws4.Cells(2, 3) = myDate
           
                End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

(*If I had the choice I would've written the operations using arrays and a difference approach but this is not allowed for now.*)

Comment: Everything does look qualified... you dont show how you get `lRow1` tho... is that getting what you expect?

Comment: What happens when it *doesn't* successfully execute?  Is `ws1` the codename for the worksheet in question?

Comment: Hi @braX. Yes, as expected.

Comment: Sorry, been a while since back on Stack: `With ws2
            
                lRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
                
            End With`

Comment: Is this your *actual code* or something "similar"?  Seems like we're not seeing something important here.  Do any of the cells on this sheet contain custom UDF's ?

Comment: Do you use `Option Explicit`? If not use it, declare all variables properly. Just in case you are missing something there you will get notified. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: @TimWilliams, the ordering of the rows scrambles randomly each run. This is a portion of the actual code - fairly lengthy - I can post all of it if that helps ...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - yes, I don't sleep well without Option Explicit.

Comment: I think there's something missing in your excerpt.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner what ever it is that is going wrong, it is not in the code part you show.

Comment: I'll redact (relabel) the sensitive stuff and post entire code after work. Won't be too long hopefully.

Comment: Hi. Full code disclosed. Apologies for the generic notation, hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Does it work with ws1 as active sheet or ws2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here where you have unqualified ranges

```
With ws2.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("A2:W" & lRow2)
    .Header = xlNo
    .Apply
End With
```

Change them to

```
With ws2.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws2.Range("A2:A" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws2.Range("B2:B" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws2.Range("F2:F" & lRow2), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange ws2.Range("A2:W" & lRow2)
    .Header = xlNo
    .Apply
End With
```

This block occurs twice. Make sure **every** `Cells`, `Range`, `Columns`, `Rows`, (any object that is located in a worksheet) object either starts with a `.` (to trigger a `With` statement) or has a worksheet and workbook qualified like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet.Range`

Comment: Had omitted as it throws 'Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method'. Error returns when qualifying inside these `Range`'s in sort block.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner My bad, the `With` points to `ws2.Sort` but for those ranges you need to point to `ws2`. See my edit.